# sklearn error - I've filled the missing values of column but still facing the below error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit the dataset to a logistic regression model but I'm facing the below error :

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

I've tried filling the missing values of the `Age` column and tried to run model fitting but it still isn't working. note- using python 3.7.1

```
train = pd.read_csv('titanic_train.csv')

X = train.drop('Survived',axis=1)
y = train['Survived']

from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split

train['Age'].isnull().values.any()

train['Age'].fillna(train['Age'].mean())

X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(train.drop('Survived',axis=1),train['Survived'],test_size=0.3,random_state=101)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The model should fit and we should be able to get the confusion matrix

Comment: what is the output that you get when you run this: `train.isnull().sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
train['Age'].fillna(train['Age'].mean())
```

`pandas` methods create copies; they do not modify the object they are called on unless you explicitly tell them to. Therefore, you need to do one of the following:

1. Set `inplace=True`:

```
train['Age'].fillna(train['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

2. Reassign:

```
train['Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(train['Age'].mean())
```

Note that doing both will not work.